# Unusual one-way screw in 95 Volvo 850

Tags: volvo, screw

I encountered these security screws attempting to remove and clean my MAF sensor. I've never seen them before and I don't know how to remove them. Any ideas?[image: Unusual one-way screw]

Comment: Those screws are used so people don’t upset how it is fitted... A decent set of grips or pliers may work but be warned...

Comment: Alternately, cut a slot in the top with a hack saw, and use a standard screw driver.